# Zsh coloring like bash

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, zsh

I want my zsh shell to look exactly like bash shell(in terms of default coloring) but my zsh shell's text is plain white. I identified this part of .bashrc which I think adds the green color to `user@pc:`

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

but pasting this in zshrc doesn't work unlike these commands:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```

I don't really know a lot about linux, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This comes more or less close to the Ubuntu bash PS1

`.zshrc`:

```
alias ll='ls -al'

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

autoload -U colors && colors
PS1="%{$fg[green]%}%n@%m%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg[cyan]%}%1~%{$reset_color%} %% "
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Can you explain whats going on in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have the absolute path displayed on your prompt, instead of only the relative one, add the following line to your .zshrc file:

```
PS1='%B%F{green}%n@%m%f:%F{blue}%/%f$vcs_info_msg_0_$%b '
```

I also think my attempt is a lot closer to the look of Ubuntu's default prompt than the accepted answer, since the text is bold and it uses $ instead of % as the "separator"